# Writing a recursive matrix pattern

Tags: matrices, loops

Consider the following matrix

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
     B_{0,0} & B_{0,1} \\
     B_{1,0} & B_{1,1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

The next matrix in the iteration is going to replace B_{i,j} with the following matrix

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
     B_{i0,j0} & B_{i0,j1} \\
     B_{i1,j0} & B_{i1,j1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

for i and j = 0 , 1, to get a 4 x 4 matrix. Is there an easy way (with for loops) to write this down? We can continue with this construction (see my comments below) to get a 8 x 8 matrix and so on.

Comment: what should the result should look like ?

Comment: Related?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156681/recursive-block-matrix

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, yes, it is related, but I am hoping for something simpler since there is no image involved. Somehow this should be more basic since it only involves latex symbols.

Comment: @percusse, it should be a 16x16 matrix with entries that look like `B_{ir,js}` as `i,j,r,s` range over 0 and 1.

Comment: Where is the recursion then?

Comment: @percusse, I made a mistake, I have edited the question. The resulting matrix is 4x4. In my original post. I can recursively define these matrices. The next one will be 8x8, with entries `B_{irp,jsq}` where all the indices range over 0 and 1. At any give stage, consider each entry in the matrix and replace it with a 2x2 matrix to get the next matrix in the iteration. I want to be able to write down at least the 4x4 and the 8x8 matrix without explicitly writing down each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really recursive. But, hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\recursematrix}{O{B}m}
 {% #1 is the (optional) symbol for the coefficient, #2 is the step
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \passerby_recursematrix:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \end{pmatrix}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_passerby_recursebody_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \passerby_recursematrix:nn
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \fp_to_int:n { 2**#2 } - 1}
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { \fp_to_int:n { 2**#2 } -1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_passerby_recursebody_tl
       {
        \exp_not:n { #1 }
        \sb
         {
          \passerby_padded_binary:nn { #2 } { ##1 },
          \passerby_padded_binary:nn { #2 } { ####1 }
         }
        &
       }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_passerby_recursebody_tl { \hspace{-2\arraycolsep} \\ }
   }
   \tl_use:N \l_passerby_recursebody_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \passerby_padded_binary:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { 0 }
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 - \fp_to_int:n { floor( ln(#2)/ln(2) ) } } { 0 }
    \int_to_bin:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\recursematrix{1}
\]
\[
\recursematrix{2}
\]
\[
\recursematrix{3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output of `\recursematrix[X]{4}` to illustrate the optional argument. It requires also

```
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{17}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the first two matrices are what the OP asked for.

I believe I have got the 3rd level, as well.  The key is in realizing that the indices are basically in binary (base 2) notation.

EDIT, To keep up with egreg, I also did 4th level.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Amatrix[2]{%
  \begin{matrix}
     B_{{#1}0,{#2}0} & B_{{#1}0,{#2}1} \\ B_{{#1}1,{#2}0} & B_{{#1}1,{#2}1} 
  \end{matrix}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\makeAnmatrix[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1matrix\endcsname[2]{%
    \begin{matrix}
      \csname\@gobble#1matrix\endcsname{{##1}0}{{##2}0} &  
      \csname\@gobble#1matrix\endcsname{{##1}0}{{##2}1}\\
      \csname\@gobble#1matrix\endcsname{{##1}1}{{##2}0} &
      \csname\@gobble#1matrix\endcsname{{##1}1}{{##2}1}
    \end{matrix}
  }%
}
\makeatother
\makeAnmatrix{AA} % ALLOWS TO DEPTH 2
\makeAnmatrix{AAA} % ALLOWS TO DEPTH 3
\makeAnmatrix{AAAA} % ALLOWS TO DEPTH 4
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}\Amatrix{}{}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}\AAmatrix{}{}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}\AAAmatrix{}{}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
\tiny
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}\AAAAmatrix{}{}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]